# Web responsive como app para android y para ios

Tags: html, android, ios, responsive

Estoy pensando en la realización de una web responsive con entrada con login y password, verificación de email, recuperación de password, y que recuerde la sesión con cookies.

El caso es que aparte de que pueda acceder por navegador me gustaría saber ***si se podría llamar a la web desde una app android y ios....y que realizara las mismas funcionalidades que por navegador....me refiero a sistema de cookies, etc...***

Gracias, espero orientación para tomar una decisión.
Amanda.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: puedes usar un WebView para llamar a tu página que, en teoría, deberían de poder hacer lo mismo. pero esto es realmente muy mala opción, estás poniendo una "traba" más para ir a tu página, puede afectar en rendimiento, más que nada.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @L.Ronquillo ... puedes aclararme un poco mas eso que comentas de que con un WebView afectaría al rendimiento de la pagina....te refieres a la velocidad de carga ....

Comment: Yo realmente lo que quiero es facilitar a la gente que entre a la web desde donde sea....desde navegador....o desde una app en android o en ios .....y que cada vez que modifique algo de la web no tenga que estar reprogramando nada en android ni en ios....pero para eso quiero asegurarme que lo mismo que se pueda hacer en un navegador se pueda hacer con un webview tanto para android como para ios....por ejemplo el tema de cookies para recordar al usuario en el login y que no tenga que estar cada vez que entre a la app metiendo usuario y contraseña

Comment: Puedes usas una [PWA](https://web.dev/progressive-web-apps/)

Comment: Gracias, probaré lo de las PWA